# Seeing invisible objects in the dope sheet

Tags: dopesheet

Is it possible to make objects that are invisible in the viewport remain in the dopesheet?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The little ghost button at the bottom of the dope sheet enables/disables showing invisible objects.

[image]